# SFINAE'ing out definitions of classes that don't exist

Tags: c++, templates, methods, sfinae

Hello template wizards,

I have been concocting a utility template which has one problem left to be solved, but cannot seem to figure it out. The code in this post is a simplification of the code in question, which exhibits the same issue.

Suppose you have a template specialisation as shown below.

```
enum class Pets { Dog, Cat, Bird };

template <Pets variant>
class Animal;

template <>
class Animal<Pets::Cat> {
  void Sound();
};

template <>
class Animal<Pets::Dog> {
  void Sound();
};

template <>
class Animal<Pets::Bird> {
  void Sound();
};

void Animal<Pets::Cat>::Sound() { printf("Meow!\n"); }
void Animal<Pets::Dog>::Sound() { printf("Woof!\n"); }
void Animal<Pets::Bird>::Sound() { printf("Peep!\n"); }
```

And then I ruin everything by saying that I might not declare the specialisation of `Animal<Pets::Bird>`. The latter definition of `::Sound()` will fail to compile, as the type doesn't exist. Now, this seems to beg for a SFINAE solution, to me, as we have an unwanted method implementation of a type that we don't want to exist.

I'd like the compiler to simply ignore that last method definition instead of failing compilation, without changing the method signature — that is, I don't want to make the method itself a template.

Do you have any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: I am not sure what precisely you want to achieve. So you **would like to not specialise `class Animal<Pets::Bird>` but specialise its member function `void Animal<Pets::Bird>::Sound() { printf("Peep!\n"); }`**? This is sadly not possible... You can trick your way around it though without specialising any classes at all and adding specialised dummy functions and some `SFINAE` if needed or using `constexpr if` again without specialisation. Similarly you might use inheritance of another base template class. If that is what you want to do I can add a corresponding answer with examples.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Yes, sort of; the point is to be able to discard non-valid member functions when the specialization is non-existent. Such that the member definition disappears if its class doesn’t exist. So, if you comment out the declaration of the class Animal<Pets::Bird>, the compiler should discard any member definitions elsewhere (the last line). I hope that makes it more clear :) I want to be able to write the member definitions, but discard them if the class doesn’t exist.

Comment: Oh, I see... I don't think that is actually possible but maybe I am mistaken.

Comment: Basically, you want the compiler to ignore a function definition entirely, although the function definition is in the source code?

Comment: @aschepler Yes, under the circumstance that the class it belongs to doesn't exist :)

Answer (score 2):

You can’t do this: SFINAE is about **overload resolution**, and while it also supports the very similar case of selecting a partial specialization, it’s not a general **conditional compilation** technique.  You can use the preprocessor, of course, and you can do tricks like declaring the unwanted function `private` so that it “doesn’t exist”, but you can’t define a function that just is never mentioned.

Comment: I choose not to believe that this isn't possible quite yet, and wait for further answers for now. I am hoping you're not right :) The type of the problem just seems very close to what you would have in a SFINAE problem; deilberately producing a type-problem which would make the compiler silently fail / ignore the chunk of code.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to conjure up a solution, which quite neatly just declares a catch-all, for those types are to be discarded — not quite what I asked for, but closer toward the goal.

This, at least, takes care of the definitions of methods that would otherwise fail compilation.

```
enum class Pets { Dog, Cat, Bird };

static constexpr Pets kChosenPet = Pets::Cat;

struct AbstractAnimal {
  virtual void Sound() = 0;
};

template <Pets variant = kChosenPet, bool B = (variant == kChosenPet)>
struct Animal : public AbstractAnimal {
  void Sound();
};

template <Pets variant>
struct Animal<variant, true> : public AbstractAnimal {
  void Sound();
};

template <>
void Animal<Pets::Cat>::Sound() {
  printf("Meow!\n");
}

template <>
void Animal<Pets::Dog>::Sound() {
  printf("Woof!\n");
}

template <>
void Animal<Pets::Bird>::Sound() {
  printf("Peep!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be I don't understand something in your question. But what's wrong with just moving declaration of `Sound()` to `Animal`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Pets { Dog, Cat, Bird };

template <Pets variant>
class Animal {
    void Sound();
};

template<>
void Animal<Pets::Cat>::Sound() { printf("Meow!\n"); }
template<>
void Animal<Pets::Dog>::Sound() { printf("Woof!\n"); }
template<>
void Animal<Pets::Bird>::Sound() { printf("Peep!\n"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

"SFINAE" means "Substitution Failure Is Not An Error". That starts with "Subsitution", an early part of the template instantiation process. And SFINAE is only Not An Error when there are alternatives for the failed template, e.g. other function overloads.

Now in `void Animal<Pets::Bird>::Sound()`, there is no Substitution, so SFINAE can't apply. We can't introduce it either - the normal way is via `std::enable_if`, which can turn a non-template declaration into a template declaration that might or might not be instantiated. But that doesn't work - this specialization cannot be a template declaration.

This case can be simplified:

```
#ifdef FOO
class Foo { int bar; }
#endif
int Foo::bar() { return 1; } // Also not fixable by SFINAE, for the same reason.
```